# Unable to get a result that is in front of my eyes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that uses fields of type VARBINARY(18) to store the primary keys

```
A sample PK: 0x001B7431C732005C4785A14F168EBD1FC5E4
```

When I try to run a simple query such as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID = '0x001B7431C732005C4785A14F168EBD1FC5E4'
```

I get no results, even though I can see the PK in *mytable*.

Does anyone know why this would be happening and how to fix it? I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use quotes.

That represents a string literal not a binary literal. The effect of it is an implicit cast of all the binary column data to string using the code page of your default collation. This will not match.

The below is all you need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE ID = 0x001B7431C732005C4785A14F168EBD1FC5E4
```

Comment: @AlbertDorson I'm pretty sure I did the same thing the first time I needed to do this.